# Training a face Recognizer with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

```
for imagePath in imagePaths:
faceImg=Image.open(imagePath).convert('L');
faceNp=np.array(faceImg,'uint8')
ID=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[1].split(".")[1])
faces.append(faceNp)
IDs.append(ID)
```

while i run this code. it only display  trains a single face amongs several faces that is been stored in the dataset. How can i be able to train many faces.

Comment: Using a Convolutional Neural Network